# Subsequential limits of unions of sequences

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Need help to check whether my proof is valid.

$(a_{m_k})$ and $(a_{n_k})$ are subsequences of $(a_k)$, so subsequences of $(a_{m_k})$ and $(a_{n_k})$ are also a subsequence of $(a_k)$. Thus $E_1\cup E_2$ is a subset of $E$.

To show the other direction, let $x$ be an element of $E$. Then there exists a subsequence $(a_{p_k})$ whose limit is $x$. $(a_{p_k})$ must contain either infinite elements of $(a_{m_k})$ or $(a_{n_k})$, otherwise it would be finite. Without loss of generality, assume it contains infinite elements of $(a_{m_k})$, then let $(a_{q_{k_j}})$ be a subsequence of $(a_{p_k})$ containing only elements of $(a_{m_k})$. Then, since $(a_{p_k})$ converges to $x$, its subsequence, $(a_{q_{k_j}})$, will also converge to $x$. But $(a_{q_{k_j}})$ is also a subsequence of $(a_{m_k})$, which implies that $x$ is also an element of $E_1$. Thus, we have shown that $E$ is also a subset of $E_1\cup E_2$. Therefore $E=E_1\cup E_2$

Below is for the next part, I am not sure if my proof is correct, its also feels very messy. Also, I cant see the link between lim sup and subsequential limits and did not deduce it using the above part if anyone could help with that.

Assume without loss of generality that $y= \limsup a_{m_k} = \max(\limsup a_{m_k}, \limsup a_{n_k})$. Then, for any $\epsilon$, there exists $K$ such that $m_k > K$ implies $\sup(a_{m_k})< y - \epsilon$. Thus, for $k>K$, if $a_k>y-\epsilon$, then it is an element of $(a_{n_k})$. Also, since ${(a_{n_k}) : n_k > K}$ is a subset of ${(a_k) : k > K}$, we have $\limsup a_k = \limsup a_{n_k}$

Answer (score 1):

Prove the following two lemmas:

**Lemma 1**: If $A,B,C$ are subsets of the extended real line such that $A = B \cup C$ then
$$\sup A = \max\{\sup B, \sup C\}.$$

**Lemma 2**: The limit supremum of an extended real sequence is equal to the supremum of the set of its subsequential limits.

Now, you've shown that
$$E = E_1 \cup E_2.$$
By Lemma 1,
$$\sup E = \max\{\sup E_1, \sup E_2\}.$$
By Lemma 2,
$$\limsup a_k = \sup E,$$
$$\limsup a_{m_k} = \sup E_1,$$
$$\limsup a_{n_k} = \sup E_2.$$
Combining these results,
$$\limsup a_k = \max\{\limsup a_{m_k}. \limsup a_{n_k}\}.$$